# any option to ignore a dns server ip from /etc/resolv.conf when doing nslookup?

Tags: linux, dns, hostname, nslookup

We have a list of dns server IPs in `/etc/resolv.conf`. When doing `nslookup` for a particular scenario we would like to ingore the second entry below, so that naming resolution occurs via other 3 DNS server IPs.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
domain example.com
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 10.10.10.1
nameserver 192.168.1.2
nameserver 192.168.1.3
```

Anyone has ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution might be to temporarily change the order of the nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` .

Another approach is to iterate through the nameservers and use them separately:

```
while read IP
do
    echo "Testing nameserver ${IP}"
    nslookup google.com "${IP}"
done < <(grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf| awk '(FNR != 2) {print $2;}')
```